# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'FirebaseApp' on REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm learning how to use firebase authentication in a react app and i have met this issue. Can somebody help me ?

i have installed firebase with npm.
This is my firebase.js file.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyA_89k1bt6Z2_1lVLb_Vwn5OL9_GgTNQEQ",
authDomain: "auth-development-59396.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "auth-development-59396",
storageBucket: "auth-development-59396.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "1003786595756",
appId: "1:1003786595756:web:fa93ae00e49a4c04c49e09"

};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

This is the dependencies package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
"firebase": "^9.0.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
 }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using the new [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which uses a different syntax than the name-spaced (`v8`) version. Try this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"; // New import

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
```

Do note that if you must refactor all your code to work with the new syntax. I'd recommend checking out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to learn more about the new syntax. Also checkout [this Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ).

---

If you wish to use the V8 name-spaced syntax, then you can use the `compat` versions:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

if (!firebase.apps.length) firebase.initializeApp({...config});

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export default app;
```